# PHP Laravel tests using mocking

Tags: php, laravel, testing, mocking, mockery

I am writing tests for my repository, and I have a page() method that takes a PaginationQuery object which consists of limit, direction and cursor for a specific model and returns a json paginator object, I am struggling with the mocking, here is my code:

My repository code:

```
   public function page(PaginationQuery $pagination)
    {
        $paginator = new Paginator($this->model);
        return $paginator->paginate($pagination->limit(), $pagination->direction(), $pagination->cursor());
    }
```

My test:

```
public function test_paging_with_mocking()
{
    // seed articles
    $seededArticles = [
        new Article(['title' => 'Article 1']),
        new Article(['title' => 'Article 2']),
        new Article(['title' => 'Article 3']),
        new Article(['title' => 'Article 4']),
        new Article(['title' => 'Article 5']),
        new Article(['title' => 'Article 6']),
    ];

    foreach ($seededArticles as $seededArticle) {
        $seededArticle->save();
    }

    $limit =  PaginationQuery::defaultLimit();
    $direction = PaginationQuery::defaultDirection();
    $cursor = PaginationQuery::defaultCursor();

    $pagination = new PaginationQuery($limit, $direction, $cursor);

    $mPaginator = M::mock(Paginator::class);
    $mPaginator->shouldReceive('paginate')->with($limit, $direction, $cursor)->andReturn([]);

    $receivedResult = $this->repo->page($pagination);
}
```

I need to achieve a couple of things here:

- to test the page() method while mocking the paginator since I don't care here about the output, I only need to assert that the limit, direction and cursor values are being passed correctly to the paginate() method.
- I also need to inject the paginator class in page() method since mocking a `new` instance of a class will cause an error in mocking this class
- in this line of the test `$mPaginator->shouldReceive('paginate')->with($limit, $direction, $cursor)->andReturn([]);` I need to add once() but when doing so I am getting the following error:

  should be called
   exactly 1 times but called 0 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that in `page` method you create new object using:

```
$paginator = new Paginator($this->model);
```

instead of passing it somehow to repository.

This causes that mock for Paginator is never used because new object is created.

You can quickly verify this, if you for `paginate` method for `Paginator` return for example `testtesttest` and add at the end of your test:

```
$this->assertEquals([], $receivedResult);
```

as you will see received result will be `testtesttest` and not `[]` although you set it using `andReturn([])` because you don't pass mocked object into repository.

The simplest solution to make test pass will be changing your `page` method into:

```
public function page(PaginationQuery $pagination, Paginator $paginator)
{
    return $paginator->paginate($pagination->limit(), $pagination->direction(), $pagination->cursor());
}
```

and now the whole test with end like this:

```
$mPaginator->shouldReceive('paginate')->once()->with($limit, $direction, $cursor)->andReturn([]);

$receivedResult = $this->repo->page($pagination, $mPaginator);
$this->assertEquals([], $receivedResult);
```

will pass, because you pass mocked object into Repository and now as you see, you will get `[]` as result even if in your `Paginator` model you return `testtest`

**EDIT**

In comment you asked how you can inject Paginator object, so there's possible solution.

Rewrite your repository to use code like this:

```
public function page(PaginationQuery $pagination)
{
    $paginator = $this->getPaginator();

    return $paginator->paginate($pagination->limit(),
        $pagination->direction(), $pagination->cursor());
}

protected function getPaginator()
{
    return new Paginator($this->model);
}
```

so you are now creating extra method to create paginator instance.

Now let's go back to your test.

Somewhere in test contructor you created repository instance. Let's assume you did this like so:

```
$this->repo = new \App\Repositories\ArticleRepository();
```

Now, we want to change it into partial mock like this:

```
$this->repo = M::mock("\\App\\Repositories\\ArticleRepository[getPaginator]")->shouldAllowMockingProtectedMethods();
```

so we tell that we will create mock for `getPaginator` method and we use `shouldAllowMockingProtectedMethods` because we wan't to mock protected method (`getPaginator` is protected method) and it cannot be done by default.

So now, the last line of test should look like this:

```
$mPaginator->shouldReceive('paginate')->once()->with($limit, $direction, $cursor)->andReturn([]);

// here we mock getPaginator method to return our mock $mPaginator
$this->repo->shouldReceive('getPaginator')->once()->andReturn($mPaginator);

$receivedResult = $this->repo->page($pagination);
$this->assertEquals([], $receivedResult);
```

so as you see we now achieved what we wanted and we don't have to pass Paginator object when running `page` method.

Comment: how can I inject the paginator class although I have to pass a model argument in the __construct?

Comment: @AliIssa Please look at my edit. Hope it will help you